# ansible replace list items with just their dictionary value

Tags: ansible

Given a host list of ips:

```
[hosts]
192.168.11.12
192.168.11.23
192.168.11.34
192.168.11.45
```

I am filtering this IP list to get a list of all the other IPs for a given node with `set_fact`.
So for host `192.168.11.12` the list results in `192.168.11.23, 192.168.11.34, 192.168.11.45` stored in `ip_list`. And so on.

That works fine.

I (manually for now) also have created a mapping to ids:

```
vars:
   my_dict:
      192.168.11.12: "abcd"
      192.168.11.23: "bcde"
      192.168.11.34: "defg"
      192.168.11.45: "vbgf"
```

So given the list from the first iteration, how do I get a list of just the id mappings?

What I want for `192.168.11.12`: `"bcde,defg,vbgf"`

I am playing with

```
-set_fact:
   id_list: " {{ ip_list | map() }} "
```

But I haven't been able to figure out.
Basically replace every entry of `ip_list` with its value from `my_dict`.

Comment: Looks like you want everything EXCEPT the one corresponding to the key in question.

Comment: yes indeed that is why I want

Answer (score 0):

I **think** that `extract` is doing what I need:

```
id_list: " {{ ip_list | map('extract', my_dict) | list }}"
```